# Use 'commands' ruby puppet function outside of puppet provider

Tags: puppet, ruby

to allow me to easier debug my providers, I sometimes wanna use 'command' in my own ruby code.

Trying to figure out how is problem.

This is how I use it inside a provider:

```
commands :wget    => '/usr/bin/wget',
         :cp      => '/bin/cp'
```

Later, I can run the command with simple:

```
wget('http://example.com')
```

Now, I tried doing this:

```
something = Puppet::Provider.commands({:wget => '/usr/bin/wget'})
something.wget('http://example.com')
```

but, I get this:

```
test.rb:15: undefined method `wget' for {:wget=>"/usr/bin/wget"}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

I also tried running:

```
wget = Puppet::Provider::Command.new('wget', '/usr/bin/wget', Puppet::Util, Puppet::Util::Execution)
puts Puppet::Util::Execution.execute(['wget','http://example.com'],{})
```

but the output is blank...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this can work.

The [commands](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider.rb#L181) method relies on another [Provider class method](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider.rb#L236) which finally uses [meta_def](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider.rb#L458) to create the method, which is then available *inside the Provider class*.

So the functionality is only available to actual subclasses of `Puppet::Provider`.

I think that the best shot at making this work would be to pull the whole functionality into a mixin module, which the `Provider` class would `extend`. Your own classes can do that as well then. (Not sure if this will really work in Puppet, though.)